# tidesdk open user-selected file

Tags: javascript, file-io, tidesdk

I'm creating a program in which the user creates projects, edits them saves them...etc. However, for opening a project, I'm stumped. I would like the user to be able to open a dialog box and select a file, then click open. Then I want to open/read that file for use in the program. Like professional softwares do. But, I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

checkout the documentation for how to use Filesystem module for reading and writing files at: http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.Filesystem

Comment: There's nothing about opening a file dialog there.

Comment: http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.UI.UserWindow-method-openFileChooserDialog

Just searching a little bit on the api doc gave me the stuff you required.

Comment: I couldn't find anything about opening a dialog box.

Comment: as second comment I gave u exact link for the API: checkout Ti.UI module apis.

`code

openFolderChooserDialog( callback, [options] ) : String
Displays the folder chooser dialog

Parameters
callback : method
a callback function to fire after the user closes the dialog
options : object (optional)
additional options for the dialog
Returns
String

`

Comment: Sorry, I mis-interpreted that.